# Remove Enums from list if they already exists in database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have a database table called `DynamicText` with the fields of `ID`, `Content`, and `TypeEnum`.

I have a list of Enums called `DynamicTextEnums` and I want to ensure that there is only one record per Enum in the database.

**Example:** I have 3 Enums called `Red`, `White`, and `Blue`. When creating a new record, I want to query the database to see if records already exist for the Enums. When i do, I find that records already exist for `Red` and `Blue`. I would then I want only `White` to appear in a drop-down list.

I'm trying to create the SQL script that queries the database and only returns the Enum values that are in the database. So if there is 7 entries for `Red` and 5 for `Blue` it would return 1 `Red` and 1 `Blue`.

Any ideas?

Comment: So what are you looking for? A SQL query that does what?

Comment: Sorry, should have been a bit more descriptive. I am looking for a SQL query.

Comment: I updated my post with what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a distinct to get unique values for TypeEnum.

```
SELECT distinct [TypeEnum]
FROM [app].[DynamicText]
```

Comment: Yep, this also worked. It's probably better to use this than simply selecting all and the grouping by `[TypeEnum]`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I simple queried the database for the `TypeEnum` field and then grouped it by that column. This way I would only have one result for each Enum.

```
SELECT [TypeEnum]
FROM [app].[DynamicText]
GROUP BY [TypeEnum]
```